# How to load a external html file?

Tags: sapui5

I just want to load a `.html` file into a `JS` view in my `UI5` Application.
This file is an external page that contains some charts..

I'm trying many things, but no success..

Thank you very much if anyone could help me on that.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What were those "many things" you tried?

The general approach is to embed the other HTML page as an iframe, using the `sap.ui.core.HTML` control, see this example:
http://jsbin.com/dutuparedeyu/1/edit?html,output

```js
new sap.ui.core.HTML({
  preferDOM: true,
  content: "<iframe src='http://www.sap.com'></iframe>"
});
```

Depending on the HTML page you could alternatively load it with an Ajax call, extract the HTML you want to display and also display it with the `sap.ui.core.HTML` control. But this approach gets difficult when the other page has scripts and CSS loaded in the head that you would also have to load into your application page.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness: Here is a solution for an XML fragment:

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Dialog title="Example" contentWidth="90%" contentHeight="90%" 
            horizontalScrolling="false" verticalScrolling="false" class="iframeHolder">
        <html:iframe src="http://www.example.com" height="100%" width="100%"/>
        <buttons>
            <Button text="{i18n>Button.ok}" press="closeDialog"/>
        </buttons>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

with this CSS rule to stretch the iframe to the total height of the Dialog

```css
.iframeHolder .sapMDialogScrollCont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

(Yes, I know that Diego asked for a JS view)