# Is it any possible in a Fiori app which includes another design studio app?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

Suppose that:
**Splitter Layout** (left-right)  the left part do navigation, and right part display the related Fioro apps.
**Flexible Column Layout** (2-column/ Full Screen Mode)  the master page do navigation, the detail page display another design studio app.

Speak freely, How to nest another Fiorai app in Fiori app?

Comment: You could embed the design studio app in an iframe within your Fiori app, so yes it is possible.

Comment: @StephenS  Thank you for your kindly reply, StephenS. Can you give me some clue to implement? ;)

Comment: iframe could be done with an html tag and within an iframe pointing to your src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344165/sap-ui5-how-to-load-a-external-html-file

Comment: and for fiori in fiori check this: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/05/sapui5-how-to-reuse-parts-of-a-sapui5-application-in-othermultiple-sapui5-applications/

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have implemented this due to the keyword "iframe", and trigger the another security question "clickjacking". But there is another story.